# Opening Excel inside web page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, excel

I have problem on my web page. I have an url of type: 'file://' but it's forbidden to open this file directly with the element `<a href="">` into a browser.

I'm looking for a plugin or something like this to execute excel and launch the file. But I would like the plugin or script to be linked to the page. I'm not looking for an add-on from google or firefox.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Voting to close this as "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource"

Comment: the http request will only send the application type. who links the application type to the application which will try to open the file is the browser (obviously, if the client has no excel installed, the browser will probably ask if the user wants to save the file)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Spreadsheet to view Excel file in browsers.

Comment: It's not possible to use Google API SpreadSheet for this. Im looked on the documentation, you can just open google- spreadsheet not spreadsheet of Microsoft Excel. :/